# Error codes when using predict() function

Tags: r

I am trying to make predictions using R but everytime I run the following code I get an error that prevents it from running saying

```
"Error in eval(predvars, data, env) : object 'running.time' not found. 

Calls : .<anonymous  ... predicts.lm -> model.frame -> model.frame.default -> eval -> eval

Execeution halted
```

```
v4mM_new = data.frame(
  v4mM = c(14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
  )
```

```
 predict(v4mM.model, newdata = v4mM_new, interval = "confidence")
```

I really don't understand what running.time has to do with any of it and I am not sure how to resolve the error

Comment: Can you show the model

Comment: Please make a minimal reproducible example to show how you came to `v4mM.model`.

Comment: ```{r}
v4mM.model = lm(v4mM ~ Running.Time, running)
v4mM.model
``` I just don't see why it is mentioningg running.time if its about v4mM

Comment: Your newdata should have `Running.Time` as column name as you are trying to predict the response v4mM  i.e. `v4mM_new = data.frame(
 Running.Time = c(14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19)
  )`